# Laravel 5.6. How to switch languages with html anchor or other tag?

Tags: php, laravel, localization, translation

I searched for a solution in Google but I didn't found any specific. I'm new in Laravel so ... I'll explain my idea and will paste my code after that.

In the Header of my pages I have a few links for to switching the languages. Actually to be specific I have four countries flags as every flag respond for the specific language. **I would like to change the language when user click on the German flag as an example. Then page need to be reloaded to update translations on it.** This functionality works only in **index Actions**.

My Source Code: This is the html in my header located in **app.blade.php**

```
<div class="languages">
@if (Config::get('app.locale') == 'bg')
   <a class="lang bg active" data-lang="bg" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/bg.png')}}" alt="bg" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@else
    <a class="lang bg" data-lang="bg" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/bg.png')}}" alt="bg" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@endif

@if (Config::get('app.locale') == 'en')
   <a class="lang en active" data-lang="en" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/gb.png')}}" alt="en" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@else
    <a class="lang en" data-lang="en" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/gb.png')}}" alt="en" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@endif

@if (Config::get('app.locale') == 'de')
   <a class="lang de active" data-lang="de" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/de.png')}}" alt="de" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@else
    <a class="lang de" data-lang="de" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/de.png')}}" alt="de" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@endif

@if (Config::get('app.locale') == 'ru')
   <a class="lang ru active" data-lang="ru" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/ru.png')}}" alt="ru" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@else
    <a class="lang ru" data-lang="ru" href="#">
        <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/ru.png')}}" alt="ru" height="14" width="20">
    </a>
@endif
```

**/Middleware/Local.php**

```
<code>


     <?php

        namespace App\Http\Middleware;

        use Closure;
        use Session;
        use App;

        class Locale
        {
            public function handle($request, Closure $next)
            {
                $locale = Session::get('locale');
                App::setLocale($locale);

                return $next($request);
            }
        }

</code>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::prefix('/home')->middleware('locale')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });
});

Route::get('/switchLang/{lang}', 'SwitchLanguageController@switchLang')->name('switchLanguage');
```

**app.js**

```
$(function(){
    var currentLanguage = document.documentElement.lang;

    // Switch languages
    $('.lang').on('click', function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        var $selectedLang = $(this).data('lang');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/switchLang/' + $selectedLang,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response)
            {
                location.href = window.location.href;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**SwitchLanguageController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use App;
use Log;

class SwitchLanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function switchLang($lang)
    {
        Session::put('locale', $lang);
        $response = ['status' => 'success', 'code' => '200', 'message' => 'Language was switched.', 'metod' => 'GET'];
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: All this code works only for the Index Actions. If I implement new action in some Controller I need manually to add 

        $locale = Session::get('locale');
        App::setLocale($locale);

in the begin of every new action. Is there any way to do not do it on every new action?

Comment: Are you not using that middleware for these other routes?

Comment: I use the same syntax for all routes but the things don't work for all. I'll give an example. I have a UsersController. Inside this Controller I have two Actions. Index Action and Profile Action. Index Action work perfect with translations but Profile Action don't. My Route for user->profile: 



Route::get('/users/profile', 'UsersController@profile')->name('profile');
Route::prefix('/users/profile')->middleware('locale')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/users/profile', function () {
        return view('profile');
    });
});

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of my issue. The problem was in my routes in **web.php**.

This code didn't work for me on **Laravel 5.6**;

```
Route::get('/users/profile', 'UsersController@profile')->name('profile');
Route::prefix('/users/profile')->middleware('locale')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/users/profile', function () {
        return view('profile');
    });
});
```

**I replaced the above code with this one!**

This work for me on **Laravel 5.6**:

```
Route::get('/users/profile', 'UsersController@profile')->name('profile')->middleware('locale');
```

Now Localization works for every route described as above. :)

Thank you very much for the help of @Devon.
The documentation of Laravel 5.6 really help me to fix the issue.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware